# How to edit content from the standard input?

Tags: command-line, invocation, unix

I would like to edit content in vim which was dynamically generated from the command-line without having the file yet.

In example:

```
$ echo This is example. | vim /dev/stdin
$ cat /etc/hosts | vim /dev/stdin
```

but it's failing with the errors:

> Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
>
> Vim: Error reading input, exiting...

It is possible to achieve that?

Comment: `:help stdin`... It's amazing how fast one can find the answers by asking their question of the built in documentation.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have to use `-` in place of the file name on the command line:

```
echo This is example. | vim -
```

The above command will open an unnamed buffer filled with the text read from the standard input.

Comment: Using a `-` for stdin is pretty much standard for commandline tools;

Answer (score 9):

This is just mostly a fun note about `bash` and `readline`, but if you set your `EDITOR` environment variable to `vim`, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> will open up the current line in `vim`. Further, if you type <kbd>Meta(Alt/Opt/Esc)</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, bash will perform an in place expansion on the current command line, i.e.:

```
$ echo $EDITOR # Assuming EDITOR was set
```

with <kbd>Meta(Alt/Opt/Esc)</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> would become

```
$ echo vim # Assuming EDITOR was set
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> would become

```
1 echo vim # Assuming EDITOR was set
~
~
/tmp/sometmpbufferfile
```

Note that upon quitting vim, the contents of the vim buffer are executed on the command line.

These features become very useful for me when I want to do multi-line commands in bash such as for loops or programs requiring here statements, and provides an interesting way to save a bit of command-line history to file for later use.

So to answer the original question, you could also write,

```
$ This is an example
```

and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to load it up in `vim`. Also you could have,

```
 $ $(cat /etc/hosts)
```

and do <kbd>Meta(Alt/Opt/Esc)</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, which would put all of the hosts file on one line and load it up in `vim` (probably not the best use of these features--however, the usefulness of these methods can be extrapolated from the few examples discussed here).

Note that I assume that your `readline` is set to `emacs` mode. If your `readline` is set to `vim` mode you can easily discover the relevant bindings by using the command:

```
bind -p
```

and searching for `edit-and-execute-command` or `shell-expand-line`, which were respectively associated with the bindings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>Meta(Alt/Opt/Esc)</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>.

Comment: You can tell bash to use vi key bindings instead of emacs.  Use `set -o vi` to turn it on.  Then you can just use the `v` mapping in normal mode to edit the current command in your editor.

Comment: For sure this is a great trick to edit the command line using vi but there are at least two problems using this method to read text from stdin: 1. `shell-expand-line` remove newlines from the expanded text and 2. `edit-and-execute-command` try to execute the command written in the buffer, whatever it is saved or not, when you quit vi.

Comment: Woah, this is awesome. I learn a new thing about readline every day, it seems...

Answer (score 4):

In bash I've found it useful to use process substitution using the `<(command)` syntax, in example:

```
vim <(echo This is example.)
vim <(cat /etc/hosts)
```

See also:

- [How to edit files non-interactively (e.g. in pipeline)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467) at Vi SE
- [How to pipe the result of a grep search into a new vi file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102089/how-to-pipe-the-result-of-a-grep-search-into-a-new-vi-file) at unix SE

Comment: Note this will *won't* work in all shells. I think it will only work in `bash` and `zsh` (and not `sh`, `ksh`, `dash`, `fish`, `csh`, `tcsh`, etc.)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Should work in ksh88 and above, I think, but yes, process substitution is not POSIX.

Comment: And pay attention to not trick yourself! When you start Vim this way it opens a buffer for a file like `/proc/PID/fd/FD`. If you write the buffer and quit, Vim doesn't complain, but the file you have written to will be removed by the OS. Using `-` as the file name the opened buffer have no file associated with it so if you try to quit without (as long you don't use a bang command or similar) saving Vim will warn you.

Comment: This is nice because it generalizes well to `vimdiff <(echo foo) <(echo bar)`.

Comment: @toro2k To follow up, it looks like using `:next` and `:prev` re-reads the stream and gets nothing. It's also worth mentioning that the processes are not parallel to one another  - e.g. `cat <(sleep 3; echo a) <(echo b)` prints in order - and while `cat` interleaves writes and reads, `vim` waits on the file to "finish reading" before displaying all but the outer frame.

Answer (score 0):

If using a pipeline to a new Vim is not a requirement, you can use Vim's ability to pull in the output of commands into the current buffer, coupled with having a non-file backed buffer (as with `:new` or editing a non-existent file)

`:read!cat /etc/hosts` in command-mode will place the output into your current buffer below the current cursor position.

Apart from having to delete the empty first line that remains when this is done on an empty buffer, this works well and is especially convenient if Vim is already running.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: It takes the output of the command and puts it into vim.

Comment: While it doesn't necessarily answer the question as asked... it is exactly the info I was looking for and this is the question that came up when I googled. Thanks!