# How can I suppress the "reading from STDIN" message from within Vim?

Tags: vimrc, options, manpages

When using Vim to read from stdin, it prints a informative message:

```
$ echo foo | vim -
Vim: Reading from stdin...

$
```

**This is just an example. The actual use doesn't allow shell constructs.** [`vim <(echo foo)`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/MATXOzr2AdM) is not an option.

Can I suppress that using *only* Vim options and/or vimrc settings?

---

In case you do need to know what this is for, I'm trying to use [Vim for reading manpages](http://murukesh.me/2015/08/28/vim-for-man.html) (shameless plug). GNU man doesn't allow shell constructs in `MANPAGER`, and by using `ftplugin/man.vim` and other things, I have successfully managed to have a comfortable experience using just `MANPAGER="vim -"`. The last remaining annoyance is the unsightly message printed after every manpage that I viewed.

Comment: Using `export MANPAGER='vim -c "%! col -b" -c "set ft=man nomod nolist ignorecase" -'` or `export MANPAGER="vim -"` I see no problem? `man ls` opens the manpage as-expected.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker and after you close it?

Comment: Nope, don't see anything...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker which version of Vim are you using? What about `echo foo | vim -Nu NONE -`

Comment: In vim, `: help less` gives some info for using it as a pager.

Comment: @mtklr true, but `$VIMRUNTIME/macros/less.sh` suffers from the same problem.

Comment: Similar: [How to edit content from the standard input?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/737/467)

Comment: For the curious: as of 7.4.1804 (2016-04-30), Vim supports a startup option that turns it into a manpager. You can set it as `export MANPAGER="vim -M +MANPAGER -"`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Starting with Vim 8.0.1308 (Nov 2017), you can use the "--not-a-term" option
with "quit":

```
$ echo hello | vi - --not-a-term -esc '%p|q!'
hello
```

Or with "exit":

```
$ echo hello | vi - --not-a-term -esc 'x!/dev/stdout'
hello
```

http://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1552

Comment: As is, this is equivalent to `cat`, but it can still be useful for applying Vimscript to the input, e.g. `+'runtime! syntax/2html.vim'` to export highlighted text as styled HTML (assuming deduced or specified filetype). There are a few options other than the ones mentioned so far; the first that comes to mind is using `mktemp` to store the command's output and using this as Vim's input. You could add Vim's redirection and shell commands to 'paste' the command result into the buffer, but this takes some more work. (Vim script files can automate lengthy invocations instead of using aliases.)

Comment: It might be possible to edit/paste output from a socket, which could be really useful if it were true. I still say the best option is a temp file, unless there are caveats worse than those for the accepted answer. For a given shell though, there may be an existing alias/builtin/syntax that simplifies some part of this process, like those listed in the manpage for zshmisc (redirections, etc.) One more - maybe you can escape the input and supply it as an argument after an argument entering insert mode, so it parses as though typed?

Comment: I see `--not-a-term` in Vim 7.4.1689 in Ubuntu 16.04 (but not 7.4.8056 on a Mac), but it doesn't suppress the message.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson See the changelog by `:help version8.txt`. `--not-a-term` option itself was added in `7.4.1419` and its behavior was changed to also suppress the *Reading from stdin...* message in `8.0.1308`. (By the way, the *N files to edit* message is also be suppressed from `8.1.1258`)

Answer (score 12):

The answer to your *exact* question:

> Can I suppress that using only Vim options and/or vimrc settings?

is: no, it's *not* possible because of the following part of the [code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/fc53ec1e9aac682a8524698240ed2bb6f7b0e300/src/fileio.c#L800)

```
    if (read_stdin)
    {
#ifndef ALWAYS_USE_GUI
        mch_msg(_("Vim: Reading from stdin...\n"));
#endif
```

which means that if you give `-` as argument to vim, then it'll mechanically show that message.

though, as a work around, if you use a file redirection instead of the `-` argument you'll get rid of the message:

```
echo "foo" | vim < /dev/tty
```

and here's an example of `MANPAGE` setting that just works™ (taken from the intertubes):

```
export MANPAGER='bash -c "vim -MRn -c \"set ft=man nomod nolist nospell nonu\" -c \"nm q :qa!<CR>\" -c \"nm <end> G\" -c \"nm <home> gg\"</dev/tty <(col -b)"'
```

Comment: When *is* `ALWAYS_USE_GUI` defined, do you know?

Comment: see feature.h (it's done when ALWAYS_USE_GUI is not defined, so basically for all unix versions).

Comment: I cannot get the workaround `echo "foo" | vim < /dev/tty` work. Doing it gives `[2]+  Stopped                 echo "foo" | vim < /dev/tty`.

Comment: Like @LéoLéopoldHertz준영, the tty trick didn't work for me (gvim gives an empty document, vim gets real confused with the keyboard inputs, but at least it doesn't receive a SIGSTOP). I've had more luck with `echo "foo" | gvim /dev/stdin` (although the non-GUI vim will still issue a complaint about that: `Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal`).

Comment: The OP was asking explicitly about vim and not gvim. There are subtle differences between the two, as you can see in the quoted snippet. Also, using tricks involving chardev files (i.e. `/dev/tty`) might depend on the terminal you're using, some terminals not respecting the standards.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 -- zmo has illustrated why I didn't provide a new answer.

Comment: Great answer, but I'd like to clarify for @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 and others wondering why wouldn't `echo test | vim < /dev/tty` work. As you can read in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514735/what-is-special-about-dev-tty, __/dev/tty__ stands for the standard input for the currently running process, and is different for each new process. In case of `echo test ...` __/dev/tty__ corresponds to the terminal's standard input, which is essentially your keyboard, and thus the trick doesn't work. If you, for example, execute that line from a standalone process, it will work as it works with MANPAGER

Comment: Well, forget my previous message. The trick in the answer is in `<(col -b)` part. That's essentially some sophisticated version of `cat` for printing man pages, and you can finally get rid of the vim's message with `echo test | vim < /dev/tty <(cat>`

Answer (score 2):

In Vim, this [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1552) has been addressed in [`234d162` commit](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/234d16286a2733adedef56784c17415ae169b9ad) (>=v8.0.1387).

> Solution:   Don't show the message with `--not-a-term` was used.

So the message is only displayed when user hasn't redirected the stdin.

---

Similar [issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/6298) has been [addressed](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/commit/bdcb2a38b3667c01efada0c6ed9414426f1c0468) in the recent version of [*Neovim*](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) (*>=v0.2.2-dev*) which you could use instead of Vim.

Once NVim v0.2.2 is released, you should be able to run:

```
$ echo foo | nvim -
```

without having the message.

Answer (score 1):

1. With vim of version *8.0.1387* and newer you can use `--not-a-term` option.
2. For older version use the following trick:

   `$ echo foo | bash -c 'vim < /dev/tty <(cat)'`

The first argument `/dev/tty` somehow tricks Vim to think the input comes from the keyboard. I guess, that's because **isatty(3)** returns True for that file. And the second argument simply passes-through everything from its standard input to Vim's standard input. Finally, `bash -c` prefix is required for the special construct `<(...)` to work if the shell doesn't support it. In *bash* the original solution can be simplified to

`$ echo foo | vim < /dev/tty <(cat)`

Comment: Both of these are covered in existing answers or the question itself. What's new here?

Comment: @muru It wasn't explained how the second case works, and people was wondering why it only worked in MANPAGE.