# Using vim as manpager: works on Linux, fails on macOS

Tags: linux, macos, bash, manpages

`:h manpager` describes how to use vim as a manpager:

```
Works on:

  - Linux
  - Mac OS
  - FreeBSD
  - Cygwin
  - Win 10 under Bash

Untested:

  - Amiga OS
  - BeOS
  - OS/2

For bash,zsh,ksh or dash by adding to the config file (.bashrc,.zshrc, ...)

    export MANPAGER="env MAN_PN=1 vim -M +MANPAGER -"
```

The line above works for me on Linux (Debian 9.2), but the same setting on a Mac (10.11 El Capitan) causes the following error every time I invoke `man`:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>57_MANPAGER:
line   16:
E684: list index out of range: 2
E15: Invalid expression: page_sec[2] page_sec[1]
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

---

#### Question 1: Is this a bug?

Should I file a bug report with vim?

> **EDIT:** This appears to be a bug in the `$VIMRUNTIME/plugin/manpager.vim` plugin. Line 18 reads:
>
> ```
> let manpage = matchstr( getline(1), '^' . pagesec_pattern )
> ```
>
> It can be fixed by replacing `getline(1)` with `getline(nextnonblank(1))`.

#### Question 2: Is there a workaround?

I've found alternate settings for the `MANPAGER` environment variable on [/r/vim](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/4xkyah/til_builtin_man_pager_in_vim/d6giyzp/) and [this StackExchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4687/2593) that make it work on macOS, but both of them cause navigation via `<C-]>` to break and give the folllowing output:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `||'
sh: -c: line 0: `(cd '/usr/share/man' && (echo ".ll 12.1i"; echo ".nr LL 12.1i"; /bin/cat '/usr/share/man/man1/vimtutor.1') | /usr/bin/tbl | /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c | ( || true))'
Error executing formatting or display command.
System command (cd '/usr/share/man' && (echo ".ll 12.1i"; echo ".nr LL 12.1i"; /bin/cat '/usr/share/man/man1/vimtutor.1') | /usr/bin/tbl | /usr/bin/groff -Wall -mtty-char -Tascii -mandoc -c | ( || true)) exited with status 512.
No entry for vimtutor in section 1 of the manual
```

> **EDIT:** Even with the fix described above, I'm continuing to get this error when navigating between man pages. It looks like it's being caused by the `( || true)` statement in the shell command, but I'm not sure where that shell command is being invoked from.

Does anyone know of a fully working solution?

---

Running vim 8.0.596

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled May  8 2017 15:44:54)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-596
```

Comment: `Is this a bug` -> Possibly? The code that errors out is in `$VIMRUNTIME/plugin/manpager.vim`. It's not very long or complicated. Adding some strategic `echo`s might help debug the problem.

Comment: There's a line in the `s:MANPAGER()` function that looks like this: `let manpage = matchstr( getline(1), '^' . pagesec_pattern )`. `getline(1)` is returning an empty string, which I think is what's causing the problem. Beyond that, I don't really know how to diagnose it. Any chance you could point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think the format of the manpages might be different on macOS? I don't have a mac machine myself, so unfortunately I can't test it.

Comment: what does the first line look like? BTW: You should report that to the plugin maintainer (or if he is unresponsive to vim-dev)

Comment: Thanks for helping me take the next step, @ChristianBrabandt. The first line of a manpage is actually blank on a Mac (or at least on my machine); the second is the one that contains the manpage name. Changing it to `getline(nextnonblank(1))` made it work. I'll shoot out an email to the maintainer now. (Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error as above when trying to navigate with `<C-]>`...)

Comment: Once you've found enough material, you should answer your own question, at least for part one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [identified as a bug](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2323) and has been (to the best of my knowledge) resolved thanks to the hard work of @ChristianBrabandt and others.

Answer (score -1):

just put this:

```
manvim() { vim -c "Man $1" -c 'silent! only'; }
```

in your bashrc or bash_profile. Then source the file & then use:

```
$ manvim 'man page name'
```

without the quotes.

Comment: FYI, `:Man` is provided by the `man.vim` _ftplugin._ That file must be sourced for the command to be defined. There are two ways to do that: 1) add `-c 'set ft=man'` to the `vim` arguments above, or 2) `execute 'source ' . $VIMRUNTIME . '/ftplugin/man.vim'` in your `vimrc`. **NOTE:** This approach **will not work** if `MANPAGER` is set (you'll get the ``sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `||'`` error mentioned in the question). This appears to be a bug, and I've notified the author via email.